# Converting to makefile

Tags: c++, gcc

```
gcc code.c -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lnetcdf -lm -fpic -o code
```

How can I convert this into a makefile? This is what I have right now:

```
IDIR =/opt/local/include
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
LDIR =/opt/local/lib

LIBS=-lm

code: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

Comment: You did not define `OBJ` in your Makefile.

Comment: please have a look on my answer, it might looks more complicated, but once you understand it, it will serve you in many projects with minor modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the following makefile would work

```
code: code.o
    gcc code.o -o code

code.o: code.c
    gcc -c code.c -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -lnetcdf -lm -fpic

clean:
    rm *.o code
```

Then it's just a matter of adding variables to the makefile. For example

```
OBJ=code.o
CC=gcc
IDIR=/opt/local/include
LDIR=/opt/local/lib
CFLAGS=-lnetcdf -lm -fpic

code: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(OBJ) -o code

code.o: code.c
    $(CC) -c code.c -I$(IDIR) -L$(LDIR) $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm *.o code
```

Answer (score 1):

I use more generic makefile:

```
NAME            := $(shell basename $(shell pwd))
OBJ             := $(NAME).o
CC              := gcc 
CFLAGS          := -fpic
LIBS            := m netcdf
LIB_DIRS        := lib_dirs
SRC_DIRS        := src 
INCLUDE_DIRS    := inc 

LIB_FLAGS       := $(patsubst %,-L%, $(LIB_DIRS))
LIB_FLAGS       += $(patsubst %,-l%, $(LIBS))
INCLUDE_FLAGS   := $(patsubst %,-I%, $(INCLUDE_DIRS))
SRC_FILES       := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *.c)

all:
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_FILES) $(INCLUDE_FLAGS) $(LIB_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJ)

clean:
    rm $(OBJ)
```

Notice:

1. put your all compile flags in CFLAGS.
2. put all libs you wanna link in LIBS (do not add -l prefix).
3. put all lib directories in LIB_DIRS (do not add -L prefix).
4. put all source dirs in SRC_DIRS.
5. put all include directories in INCLUDE_DIRS (do not add -I prefix).